# I am trying to pass 2 sums from a subroutine back to the main function in C

Tags: arrays, c, average, program-entry-point, subroutine

I am currently trying to take a sum from two different subroutine and pass it back to the main function, but every time I do this, it just comes up with a zero value and I am unsure why. I have tried putting my print statements in the main function and just doing calculations in the subroutines and that still didn't work, so I know that my variables aren't returning right and my sum is an actual number. How do I pass my variable sum back to my main function correctly?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int X[2000];
int Y[2000];


int main()
{
   FILE*fpdata1= NULL;

   FILE*fpdata2 = NULL;

   fpdata1=fopen("DataSet1.txt","r");
   fpdata2=fopen("DataSet2.txt","r");

   if(fpdata1==NULL || fpdata2 == NULL)
   {
       printf("file couldn't be found");
   }

   int i=0;

   while(i<2000)
   {
       fscanf(fpdata1,"%d!",&X[i]);
       fscanf(fpdata2,"%d!",&Y[i]);
      // printf("This is X: %d\n",X[i]);
      // printf("This is Y: %d\n",Y[i]);


       i++;
   }

    fclose(fpdata1);
   fclose(fpdata2);

   avgX(X);
   avgY(Y);

   float sum;
   float sumY;
   float totalsum;
   float totalavg;

   totalsum= sum + sumY;
   totalavg= totalsum/4000;

   printf("Sum X: %f\n\n",sum);


   printf("Total sum: %f\n\n",totalsum);

   printf("The total average is: %0.3f\n\n",totalavg);

   return 0;

}

int avgX(int X[])
{
    int i=0;
    float averageX;
    float sum;
    sum = 0;

    while (i<2000)
    {
        sum += X[i];
        i++;

    }
    averageX = sum/2000;

    printf("Sum of X: %f\n\n",sum);
    printf("The sum of Data Set 1 is: %0.3f\n\n",averageX);

      return(sum);



}


int avgY(int Y[])
{
    int i=0;
    float averageY;
    float sumY;
    sumY = 0;

    while (i<2000)
    {
        sumY += Y[i];
        i++;

    }
    averageY = sumY/2000;



    printf("Sum of Y: %f\n\n",sumY);
    printf("The sum of Data Set 2 is: %0.3f\n\n",averageY);
    return (sumY);



}
```

Comment: The local variable `sum` in `main` is unrelated to the local variable with the same name in the function `avgX`.  You are seeing undefined behavior by attempting to read the value of the uninitialized variable.

Comment: You do not assign return values from your functions to any variable. Also you calculate floating point sums but return integer type.

Comment: After ` printf("file couldn't be found");` should you not exit as you cannot go any further

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it would appear you are expecting the lines

```
avgX(X);
avgY(Y);
```

to somehow update the `sum` and `sumY` variables in the `main` function. This is a fundamental misunderstanding of how memory is accessed.

Local variable declarations with the same identifier are not shared between functions. They can be accessed only from within the function in which they are declared (and only for the duration of the function call).

In this example, the `apples` variables in each of the functions have absolutely no correlation to one another. Expecting this program to print `15` is wrong. This program has *undefined behavior* because `foo` and `bar` read values from uninitialized variables.

```
void foo(void) {
    int apples;
    /* This is undefined behaviour,   
     * as apples was never initialized. Do not do this. */
    apples += 5;
}   

void bar(void) {
    int apples;
    /* This is undefined behaviour,   
     * as apples was never initialized. Do not do this. */
    printf("%d\n", apples);               
}                                         
                                  
                                  
int main(void) {
    int apples = 10;
    foo();
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of this, you'll want to utilize the arguments and return values of your functions. In this example, in `main` we pass the *value* of `apples` as an argument to `foo`, which adds `5` to this value and *returns* the result. We assign this return value, overwriting our previous value.

```
int foo(int val) {
    return value + 5;
}   

void bar(int val) {
    printf("%d\n", val);
}                                 
                                  
int main(void) {                  
    int apples = 10;       
                   
    apples = foo(apples);
    bar(apples);

    return 0;
}
```

Again note that the `val` parameters do not refer some "shared variable", they are local to both `foo` and `bar` individually.

---

As for the specifics of your program:

- The functions `avgX` and `avgY` do the exact same thing, just with different identifiers.

It would be better to write a more generic summation function with an additional length parameter so that you are not hard-coding data sizes everywhere.

```
int sum_ints(int *values, size_t length) {
    int result = 0;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result += values[i];
    
    return result;
}
```

You can then easily write averaging logic utilizing this function.

- You do check that your file pointers are not invalid, which is good, but you don't halt the program or otherwise remedy the issue.
- It is potentially naive to assume a file will always contain exactly `2000` entries. You can use the return value of `fscanf`, which is the number of *conversions* that took place, to test if you've failed to read data. Its also used to signify errors.
- Though the fact that global variables are *zeroed-out* saves you from potentially operating on unpopulated data (in the event the files contain less than `2000` entries), it would be best to avoid global variables when there is an alternative option.
- It might be better to separate the reading of files to its own function, so that failures can be handled per-file, and reading limits can be untethered.
- `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` are the correct, valid signatures for `main`.

---

With all that said, here is a substantially refactored version of your code. Note that an [*implicit conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) takes place when we assign the integer return value of `sum_ints` to our floating point variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 2000

int sum_ints(int *values, size_t length) {
    int result = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result += values[i];

    return result;
}

size_t read_int_file(int *dest, size_t sz, const char *fname) {
    FILE *file;
    size_t i;

    if ((file = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Critical: Failed to open file: %s\n", fname);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        if (fscanf(file, "%d!", dest + i) != 1)  
            break;

    fclose(file);

    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    int data_x[DATA_SIZE] = { 0 },
        data_y[DATA_SIZE] = { 0 };

    size_t data_x_len = read_int_file(data_x, DATA_SIZE, "DataSet1.txt");
    size_t data_y_len = read_int_file(data_y, DATA_SIZE, "DataSet2.txt");

    float sum_x = sum_ints(data_x, data_x_len),
          sum_y = sum_ints(data_y, data_y_len);

    float total_sum = sum_x + sum_y;
    float total_average = total_sum / (data_x_len + data_y_len);

    printf("Sums: [X = %.2f] [Y = %.2f] [Total = %.2f]\n"
           "The total average is: %0.3f\n",             
            sum_x, sum_y, total_sum,
            total_average);
}
```

Comment: A (E) for Explanation